# Set Windows (10) default DNS server with custom port (not 53)

Tags: windows, networking, dns

Could not find the info. Is it possible somehow to set `Windows` default DNS server with a custom port other than 53?

So I belive not possible:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181
"Except in extraordinary circumstances, this will be the well known port assigned for DNS queries [RFC1700].

Comment: If you could it would break DNS. "DNS primarily uses the User Datagram Protocol (UDP) on port number 53 to serve requests. "

Comment: How this can even be? nslook has `set port` command, no problems should be with other port. The issue if it possible to set on the network interface, it is not possible using standard UI.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2181 "Except in extraordinary
   circumstances, this will be the well known port assigned for DNS
   queries [RFC1700]."

Comment: Well, so I'm in extraordinary circumstances I believe. Ok.))

Comment: "I'm in extraordinary circumstances" So what are they? This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Nevermind, I can handle) Thanks anyway!